# Android custom Application class with set up at manifest don't work with ClassCastException

Tags: java, android

I don't know what is problem, because in my other projects it is work. I'm use custom application class and register it in my manifest file:

```
package ru.jooogle.sunshine.admin_pc.sunshine_reborn;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import ru.jooogle.sunshine.admin_pc.sunshine_reborn.model.network.NetworkService;

    public class SunshineApplication extends Application {
        private NetworkService networkService;

        public static SunshineApplication get(Context context) {
            return (SunshineApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
        }

        public NetworkService getNetworkService() {
            if (networkService == null) {
                networkService = new NetworkService();
            }

            return networkService;
        }
    }
```

And manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.jooogle.sunshine.admin_pc.sunshine_reborn">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".SunshineApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SunshineActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In Activity onCreate i do:

```
SunshineApplication sunshineApplication = SunshineApplication.get(this);
```

and i get ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to ru.jooogle.sunshine.admin_pc.sunshine_reborn.SunshineApplication
```

I don't know what is it, help, please.

Comment: Please post the entire Java source file for `SunshineApplication`.

Comment: I post all code that's my project of SunshineApplication

Comment: You are missing the `package` line and the `import` statements, at minimum. Since those may be the source of your problem, I suggest that you edit your question and put in the complete contents of `SunshineApplication.java`.

Comment: I added full text now

Comment: one required change getApplication instead of getApplicationContext

Comment: Ok, but i created now new project where i use this code, and it work. I don't know what is it

Comment: That is very strange. It is as if your `android:name` in the `<application>` element is being ignored. If you have not done so already, clean the project (e.g., from the Android Studio main menu). You might also look at the merged manifest to confirm that your `android:name` attribute is in there and is not somehow being replaced.

Comment: thanks, but i does it, not work. May be this is android studio bag

Comment: I found solution, friends. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm  found solution. In this project i use experimental feature buildCach in gradle.properties :

```
android.enableBuildCache=true
```

if comment this line and rebuild project, problem gone